# Which Upanishad is this from and what does it mean: "When a blade of grass is cut, the whole universe quivers"?

Tags: upanishads

***When a blade of grass is cut, the whole universe quivers.***

The internet claims that this is from an Upanishad. Which Upanishad is it from, what is the exact phrase in Sanskrit, and what does it mean?

Comment: who claims it ? can you source the site/blog from which you copied the quote ?

Comment: @mar- The book is Mindpower into the 21st Century by John Kehoe. I'm unable to put a link in here.